# Pattern for no-allocation loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

Say we're writing a browser app where smooth animation is critical. We know garbage collection can block execution long enough to cause a perceptible freeze, so we need to minimize the amount of garbage we create. To minimize garbage, we need to avoid memory allocation while the main animation loop is running.

But that execution path is strewn with loops:

```
var i = things.length; while (i--) { /* stuff */ }

for (var i = 0, len = things.length; i < len; i++) { /* stuff */ }
```

And their `var` statements <s>allocate memory</s> can allocate memory that the garbage collector may remove, which we want to avoid.

So, **what is a good strategy for writing loop constructs in JavaScript that avoid allocating memory each one?** I'm looking for a general solution, with pros and cons listed.

---

Here are three ideas I've come up with:

### *1.)* Declare "top-level" vars for index and length; reuse them everywhere

We could declare `app.i` and `app.length` at the top, and reuse them again and again:

```
app.i = things.length; while (app.i--) { /* stuff */ }

for (app.i = 0; app.i < app.length; app.i++) { /* stuff */ }
```

**Pros:** Simple enough to implement. **Cons:** Performance hit by dereferencing the properties might mean a Pyrrhic victory. Might accidentally misuse/clobber properties and cause bugs.

### *2.)* If array length is known, don't loop -- unroll

We might be guaranteed that an array has a certain number of elements. If we do know what the length will be in advance, we could manually unwind the loop in our program:

```
doSomethingWithThing(things[0]);
doSomethingWithThing(things[1]);
doSomethingWithThing(things[2]);
```

**Pros:** Efficient. **Cons:** Rarely possible in practice. Ugly? Annoying to change?

### *3.)* Leverage closures, via the factory pattern

Write a factory function that returns a 'looper', a function that performs an action on the elements of a collection (a la `_.each`). The looper keeps private reference to index and length variables in the closure that is created. The looper must reset `i` and `length` each time it's called.

```
function buildLooper() {
  var i, length;
  return function(collection, functionToPerformOnEach) { /* implement me */ };
}
app.each = buildLooper();
app.each(things, doSomethingWithThing);
```

**Pros:** More functional, more idiomatic? **Cons:** Function calls add overhead. Closure access [has shown](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/closure-vs-object-performance.html) to be slower than object look-up.

Comment: I'm *very* suspicious of your premise. Why do you think `var` allocates memory that the GC cares about? Even in a simple and stupid stack-based bytecode VM like CPython, the local variables are a native array in the frame object and never allocated separately or added/removed while a function is running.

Comment: Here's my reasoning. Because of JavaScript's closures, `with` and `eval`, a function's execution context (a type of frame object) can survive after the function returns.  An EC that must survive will be allocated on the heap, but exactly when/how this happens depends on the engine. (Clever engines like V8 will optimize, using the stack for local vars -- only copying context vars to the heap when they must outlive the function call).  If/when these heap objects become unreferenced/inaccessible, they will be GC'd.

Comment: Okay, but that would be a reason (if it was true, and even then I'd be very suspicious) to not *call functions* at all, not one to avoid `var`. In the absence of `eval`/`with` (which can be determined statically, or assumed and checked at runtime) it's trivial to just allocate space for all local variables in the EC when you create it, so individual `var`s don't need any allocation.

Comment: BTW @delman -- thanks for questioning the premise. You prompted me to do more research. After which it seems to me that enough factors that come into play as to make the value of these types of optimizations debatable. Or, possibly a moot point if one takes care to design functions smartly. FWIW, I've seen libraries like Google Closure use a `function(a, b, returnValue)` pattern to avoid allocations. Also see [this article on writing low-garbage JS](https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And their var statements allocate memory can allocate memory that the garbage collector may remove, which we want to avoid.

This is slightly misinformed. Simply using `var` does not allocate memory on the heap. When a function is called, each variable used in the function is allocated in advance on the stack. When the function completes execution, the stack frame is popped and the memory is immediately dereferenced.

Where garbage collection-related memory concerns become a problem is when you're allocating objects on the heap. That means any of the following:

- Closures
- Event listeners
- Arrays
- Objects

For the most part, anything where `typeof foo` returns `"function"` or `"object"` (or any of the new ES6 `typeof` return values) will generate an object on the heap. There's probably more that I can't think of right now.

The thing about objects on the heap is that they can refer to other objects on the heap. So for instance:

```
var x = {};
x.y = {};
delete x;
```

In the example above, the browser simply can't deallocate the slot for `x`, because the value contained within it is of variable size. It lives on the heap, where it could then point to other objects (in this case, the object at `x.y`). Another possibility is that there's a second reference to the same object:

```
var x = {};
window.foo = x;
delete x;
```

The browser simply can't remove the object at `x` from memory, since something else is still pointed at it.

So long story short, don't worry about removing variables, because they work perfectly well and are totally performant. Heap allocations are the real enemy when it comes to garbage collection, but even a few small heap allocations here and there won't hurt most apps.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you very much for taking the time to give a thorough answer to my question.